# I'm trying to split a column of data into multiple columns(3) with pandas. I'm failing to get the split colums onto the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Trying to split text data and assign the split columns back to the same data frame. it's the assignment that's failing.
This code is giving the error:ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (2872, 3)

`africa_raw_df['city', 'province', 'country']=africa_raw_df.location.str.split("," , expand=True)``
I was expecting the data to be split on the commas and allocated to new columns city, province, and country.

[This is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIDbH.jpg)
I'm expecting those columns to be on the main data frame

Answer (score 0):

You need double brackets. Otherwise you're almost right!

```
africa_raw_df[['city', 'province', 'country']] = africa_raw_df.location.str.split("," , expand=True)
```